# Hadoop version across all Nodes

Tags: hadoop

Does the version and installation location of Hadoop have to be the exact same across all nodes in the cluster? For example, if I have hadoop-0.18.2 on my master node in /usr/local/hadoop does the version and the installation directory have to be the same across all data nodes?

Comment: You can try `cssh` if you want to help with the entering things on all nodes at once - this tool has been invaluable to me as there's no way I'm going to do the same thing 10 times to get it on each node! http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do have to be identical otherwise you will encounter major issues.

Comment: Ok. So i do have to make sure I use the same version everywhere (simple renaming a the installation directory wudn't work)? Also, the installation directory has to be exactly the same?

Comment: Do the user names have to be the same as well across all nodes?? Please reply.

Comment: The username have to be the same aswell otherwise you will encounter configuration issues.